# How to perform static code analysis?

Tags: python, php, static-analysis, code

I am working as QA.I want to test the static code analysis of my
project. How to get start this ? Can you suggest a good tool to
 perform static code analysis ?   My project is running in php, python,
javascript. How to test the static code analysis of these code ?

Is it possible to add plugin sonarqube to idea Inellij ? Is it easy way to choose to test ? OR just install sonarqube on  my ubuntu pc.
Which should I choose to use  sonarqube ?

Comment: Static analysis tool is a technique, it has no direct relationship with Jenkins.

There are various tools that you can find from Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins is a continuous integration server, also known as a build server. It takes the source code and builds it, runs tests and execute any other commands you see fit. Afterwards it can report about the status of these commands like success and or failures.

Code analysis programs can be started and reported on with Jenkins, but this is not something that is included by default.

A common open source code analysis tool I would look at is [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). It has plugins for most programming languages. SonarQube has some command-line tools to process the code and then push it to the web-server for view the results. Jenkins or any other build can push the results from the command-line tool to the SonarQube web-application.

Comment: Hai.. Is it possible to add plugin sonarqube to idea Inellij ?  Is it easy way to choose to test ?

Comment: Check http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/ I never used it though.

Comment: No idea, that is a different question, questionably offtopic on SQA.SE :)

Comment: I quiet to sonarqube, because last 4 days I was trying to install sonarqube but cannot get a success. So what's your opinion still I do with sonarqube or look with any other tool ?

Comment: Maybe the commandline nature makes it a bit harder to install sonarqube, but I remember we installed it within an hour last time. There are some alternatives search the internet. Still I would go for Sonar. Maybe try to install with a sysadmin coworker

Comment: Are you sure it is one of the best tool for code analysis ? And I'm following this site http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/   Still making a problem what should do to overcome this situation ?

Comment: I wouldn't use a year old guide. Probably something has changed. Use the documentation http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/6966044

Comment: There are no free alternatives I think that are still updated regularly. Also it supports a lot of languages making Sonar the tool you can use for most jobs in the future.

Comment: This is for windows but i'm using ubuntu os

Comment: All steps have Linux, Mac and windows commands if they differ. It's not windows focused it's for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

SonarLint can be fully integrated with the IntelliJ or Eclipse without any difficulties.
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-intellij

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for static analysis tools, you can probably find a lot of good information with a simple google or wikipedia search.  What to do to get started depends heavily on what tool you are using.  One Static Analysis tool that you can use in [nDpend](http://www.ndepend.com/) and if you want more information or thoughts on how to use it, Erik Dietrich has some really good posts on their [blog](https://blog.ndepend.com/author/erik-dietrich/) with useful and interesting ways to use static analysis